# Converting 8 bit bmp to halftone bmp

Tags: verilog

I am explaining my question in detail now as I am realizing that I did not explain my question well.

I am a beginner in Verilog. To learn the language I am writing some sample applications.
At present I am writing Verilog code to convert 8 bit BMP image to half tone BMP image using [Floyd-Steinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) algorithm.
Basically I am converting  8 bit pixels into 1 bit using the said algorithm.

I found the sample code for this algorithm in the book [Advanced Digital Design with the Verilog HDL - Michael D. Ciletti](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Advanced_Digital_Design_with_the_Verilog.html?id=6tW8PQAACAAJ) on page number 555. I have successfully simulated the design in ModelSim.

The problem is the example is given for an image of size 6 x 8, but to learn and practice I am trying to convert this code for different formats and sizes. As a first goal I am trying to modify this code (which I have already understood well) to work for images of size 1000 x 1000. Since the example was for only 48 pixels (6 x 8), it was easier to write the instructions inside the module manually, as shown in the code given below.  But in case I have 10,00000 pixels (1000 x 1000) how do I change the code. 
I cannot write such equations:

```
  PPDU a0(err_1,htpv_1[1],8'b00,8'b00,8'b00,8'b00,pixel_1);
```

10,00000 manually (kindly see the code given below).

I guess there has to be some way for automating this job.

In C I can use for loops *for* autoamting many things. But being a novice in Verilog I am unable to proceed. I will really aprecaite if somebody can point me to a useful link.

```
// pixel processor datapath unit//
module PPDU(err_0,htpv,err_1,err_2,err_3,err_4,pv);
output [7:0]err_0;
output htpv;
input [7:0]err_1,err_2,err_3,err_4,pv;
wire [9:0]cpv,cpv_round,e_av;
parameter w1=2,w2=8,w3=4,w4=2;
parameter threshold =128;
assign e_av=(w1*err_1+w2*err_2+w3*err_3+w4*err_4)>>4;
assign cpv=pv+e_av;
assign cpv_round=(cpv<threshold)?0:255;
assign htpv=(cpv_round==0)?0:1;
assign err_0=cpv-cpv_round;
endmodule

module image_converter (pixel_1,pixel_2,pixel_3,pixel_4,pixel_5,pixel_6,pixel_7,pixel_8,pixel_9,
   pixel_10,pixel_11,pixel_12,pixel_13,pixel_14,pixel_15,pixel_16,pixel_17,
   pixel_18,pixel_19,pixel_20,pixel_21,pixel_22,pixel_23,pixel_24,pixel_25,
   pixel_26,pixel_27,pixel_28,pixel_29,pixel_30,pixel_31,pixel_32,pixel_33,
   pixel_34,pixel_35,pixel_36,pixel_37,pixel_38,pixel_39,pixel_40,pixel_41,
   pixel_42,pixel_43,pixel_44,pixel_45,pixel_46,pixel_47,pixel_48,htpv_1,
      htpv_2,htpv_3,htpv_4,htpv_5,htpv_6
      );
 input [7:0]pixel_1,pixel_2,…..,pixel_47,pixel_48;
 output [1:8]htpv_1,htpv_2,htpv_3,htpv_4,htpv_5,htpv_6;
 wire [7:0]err_1,err_2,……., err_47,err_48;
 PPDU a0(err_1,htpv_1[1],8'b00,8'b00,8'b00,8'b00,pixel_1);
 ...
 PPDU a7(err_8,htpv_1[8],err_7,8'b00,8'b00,8'b00,pixel_8);                       
 PPDU b1(err_9,htpv_2[1],8'b00,8'b00,err_1,err_2,pixel_9);
 ...     PPDU b8(err_16,htpv_2[8],err_15,err_7,err_8,8'b00,pixel_16);
 PPDU c1(err_17,htpv_3[1],8'b00,8'b00,err_9,err_2,pixel_17);
 ….
 PPDU c8(err_24,htpv_3[8],err_23,err_15,err_16,8'b00,pixel_24);
 PPDU d1(err_25,htpv_4[1],8'b00,8'b00,err_17,err_18,pixel_25);
 ….
 PPDU d8(err_32,htpv_4[8],err_31,err_23,err_24,8'b00,pixel_32);
 PPDU e1(err_33,htpv_5[1],8'b00,8'b00,err_25,err_26,pixel_33);
 ….
 PPDU e8(err_40,htpv_5[8],err_39,err_31,err_32,8'b00,pixel_40);
 PPDU fi(err_41,htpv_6[1],8'b00,8'b00,err_33,err_34,pixel_41);
 ….
 PPDU f8(err_48,htpv_6[8],err_47,err_39,err_40,8'b00,pixel_40);  
 end
 endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. You can use the `generate` statement as a kind of loop to instantiate modules which are too numerous to type out. I am less familiar with this construct, but perhaps a google search for this keyword will point you in the right direction.
2. While verilog is a description language for hardware, nothing requires you to actually write out the file by hand. You can feel free to use any programming language you like to generate the verilog file (Perl is my favorite). If you have to generate 1 million modules according to some algorithm, then you can write a simple script which prints a 1 million line verilog file. You don't have to write it manually.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are instantiating a module for each pixel.  That is all well and good, but will end up using a lot of hardware for 1000x1000 images, as each module is a bunch of gates and flipflops.  This will result in you converting the whole image 'at-once', which also means you have to get the whole image to this hardware 'at once' which is an awful lot of pins.

What you probably want to do is either:

- store the image in memory, and then write a state machine to read the relevant parts of the memory, perform the dithering and write it back
- stream the image through some logic which keeps just enough knowledge of the previous pixels to perform the dithering.  I'm not that familiar with F-S dithering, but it probably only needs knowledge of one or two lines above the one being processed.